# Is it possible to create type safety on a function that creates a promise out of a callback and a list of arguments?

Tags: typescript, promise, callback

I have defined a function that takes another function and a list of arguments as parameters to create a promise, like so:

```js
  async callbackToPromise (func: Function, ...args: any[]): Promise<any> {
    // Immediately return if the function argument is undefined, to avoid errors.
    if (func === undefined) {
      console.warn('Function undefined in callbackToPromise.')
      return await Promise.reject(
        new Error('Function undefined in callbackToPromise.')
      )
    }
    const call = new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      func((resolveStr: unknown) => {
        if (resolveStr !== undefined) {
          return resolve(resolveStr)
        } else {
          return reject(new Error('No data returned'))
        }
      }, ...args)
    })
    return await call
  }
```

I use this function to get promises out of a not insignificant variety of API calls in my environment that all take a callback as the first parameter and return nothing (just calling the callback with data instead). These have a variety of additional parameters and call the callback with a variety of return types.

It generally works well, but I run into some frustration sometimes when writing up new API calls that I haven't used before as Typescript can't tell me which parameters to pass for `...args` and I have to spend extra time checking against the typing I built for the API to know exactly what to pass in and how.

In use, the functions that call `callbackToPromise` all define their own parameters and that's what I use outside of the interface code, but it would be more convenient when defining a new interface function if I could keep type safety there, too. And be less error prone if I realize a typing in my API type file is wrong or incomplete and needs to be updated.

**Is there any way to tell Typescript "only accept `...args` matching the parameters of the function I pass in as `func`?**

Additional details:

I am calling `callbackToPromise` with black box functions I have no access to, for example one with a signature like this (which lives as a method of `window.external`):

```js
  RemoveProblem: (
    callback: Function,
    prid: number,
    stopDate: string,
    isApproxDate: boolean,
    reason: TProblemRemoveReason
  ) => void
```

An example of how I am using it in my code (part of a longer function definition):

```js
  const result: number = await this.helpers
      .callbackToPromise(
        this.wrappedWindow.external.RemoveProblem,
        prid,
        stopDate,
        isApprox,
        reason
      )
      .catch((error: Error) => {
        console.error(`Error removing problem: ${error.message}`)
      })
```

What I would like, ideally, would be for `callbackToPromise` to give a type error on compile if I try to pass parameters that don't match the function I pass it as the first argument.

Side Note: When I originally attempted to implement CRice's answer below, I got an issue where, when I try to actually call the function with an `await`, Typescript would say `Type 'number | void' is not assignable to type 'number'. Type 'void' is not assignable to type 'number'.`  This ended up being due not to the `Parameter<T>` part of the script, but the return of the `.catch` part not returning a value.

[Playground based on CRice's second example showing the error](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/FAYw9gdgzgLgBCAhgG2QI0SA1gFTABQCcwBbASygFM4BeORKATwhDgB4BBOSgDxkogATKPQiMA2gF0ANHABi3PgOFwAFAGEAQgC41hSlACuyGLsRiAlLQB8oxrIB0TxIQDmUXRys1b5xtdUAM0MWXTlHZzcPOC9dIlIKSjZ8F0QSSn5CKGTU9MzsuWtxAAZJItLbHzgAb2A4ergAeka4AEkSdMEyRH5kRjh9GENCCDgyQLgYAAtqYJYYMkh6N0N0iHgKOBDBSkCyCEpBWRgwegA3MDJBbkJiLIc6hvG1OdYad62hXf3Dq1qGgEISBQMDISgOADuLggqgA5HIQiAFkttt8Dtd9ggUOhMLgCMRyFQHLCLI9AQMMsNRogoWR4PFCeD9AArShI1Rk8kNA4QuAAUVuYEIcIR80Wo1Re3RY1GSFQGGweAZiWJpK5cDVDQAvpzwNB4HLkLQ4Dy4MqqKpVPoQcgzpRZCy2TBvLZ-lzXpbraC7QBlGCEF01Tnq55Wgzeyh%20whwACEH0lP0Ef2D6oagypFJtdrDWcj-s1qbgWu4yCoQcL5PTIwprPZpoFdzhADlToIeogKUMRocSQXUzr1VqIg4XO4%201q%201XZdjgDrgDBGAAHag4eJoMEkABKlBIYDt24YSzoISwEDAEIgAG5gMAdiBkC5qHrYHBt7u7WuN7pVIaFVhv4QugQKsaCUAGNhwBcVyyIuhBXEBIFgbIsBgIuAAiPSULosBwRAriyBQHCLrBYA8Bh-C6GgYCgpQ5gOrRIIQLoq7EOuO5vnulAHoxgZQYIN6-riSoEokqgcR%20rEbrIABE0myAAzMchCGPacCyVYzSTEuBhwGAEyLrkGRgSIsKwVcsKiNcsKjlAAD6xQWY%20MrgCQBkLGxDhwDg2lwLCOH7K4FmbGe8AMFAZCuBAiBsZMpwLsuvnASQoGELCDzPvAPDGoJir4gkFriZQn47gpMlyXAgQoFQZUaS0ADqQpYFA9G5iIJxmiJVBsAcdqENYDzAAwzCsKogZuvUGVwP0dA0ogdJwFlmn9FMDBaQlSUpbqwLwNaximCaiHRjNtIGtif7CfllAcuqhXFSQ0gpvUAAsD3qrCsKve6VX2o9vmwpyfYAg4SAwCAUyWmBdy6A2Qpjb9ALPjRDiQ0KqgAAYw9G%20jvgFcAkWxJC6AAJNUKOEA46RQFAiCuJQWpo4D2qkjqQA)

Comment: [Don't use `any` unless you are in the middle of migrating from vanilla JS to TS](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/declaration-files/do-s-and-don-ts.html#any). `any` effectively disables typescript wherever it is used.

Comment: not sure to understand your requirement. Do you have an example of the expcted result ? Because as I understood, you want to transform a function (func) to a promise ?
Or you just want to execute the function and return its result ?

Comment: @Mulan I can change to `...args: unknown[]` without issue, but changing the return type to `Promise<unknown>` causes everywhere I have called it to tell me 'unknown is not assignable to (whatever type)'.  I know what type of argument the callback will receive but unsure how to specify that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First I'll point out that if you are using nodejs, you can use the built in [`util.promisify`](https://nodejs.org/dist/latest-v8.x/docs/api/util.html#util_util_promisify_original) function for this purpose and it comes with correct types already. In the broswer, there will be plenty of packages you can use for the same effect. However, you can also modify your function to infer the promise type by using generics.

This makes heavy use of [the helper type `Parameters<F>`](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/utility-types.html#parameterstype) which extracts the type of the parameters of the type `F` (assuming `F` is a function type).

The essential part of it is that you can use the `Parameters` helper type to extract the type of the first parameter of the callback that your function will accept. This is the type that your promise will resolve to.

```
const callbackToPromise = async <A extends any[], F extends (CB: (result: any) => any, ...args: A) => any>(func: F, ...args: A): Promise<Parameters<Parameters<F>[0]>[0]> => {
    // Immediately return if the function argument is undefined, to avoid errors.
    if (func === undefined) {
        console.warn('Function undefined in callbackToPromise.')
        return await Promise.reject(
        new Error('Function undefined in callbackToPromise.')
        )
    }
    const call = new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        func((resolveStr) => {
            if (resolveStr !== undefined) {
                return resolve(resolveStr)
            } else {
                return reject(new Error('No data returned'))
            }
        }, ...args)
    })
    return call
}
```

There is a bit to unpack there, but here is what is going on:

- `A extends any[]` declares a generic `A` which is an array of any other types. This will be used in a moment to represent the type of the *all but the first* arguments to `func`.
- `F extends (CB: (result: any) => any, ...args: A) => any` declares an additional generic `F`, which is a function that accepts a callback as its first parameter and then uses the earlier generic `A` to represent all the remaining parameters.

Finally the return type:

- `Promise<Parameters<Parameters<F>[0]>[0]>` just says that the promise will resolve to the type of the first argument of the callback that the function `F` accepts.

Using that definition, you seem to get the correct inferences when using it:

```
const numericCallback = (cb: (v: number) => void, num: number): void => {
    cb(num);
}

const promisifyNumericCallback = callbackToPromise(numericCallback, 56) // This is inferred as a Promise<number>
```

---

[Playground Link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#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%20whwACEHwlP0EfyDwYagypFOttrDWcjfo1qbgmu4yCogcL5PTIwprPZJv5dzhADlToIeogKUMRocSQXU9rg5qIg4XO4%205q%201WZdjgNrgDBGAAHag4eJoMEkABKlBIYFt24YSzoISwEDAEIgAG5gMAdiBkC5qLrYHBt7vbWuN7pVAb5VgwoiyIQLIi6EFcugQKsaCUIQsiwGAi4ACI9JQuiwGBECuLIFAcIuoFgDwyH8LoaBgKClDmPaFEghAuirsQ647m%20e6UAeNEBhcVw3r%20uKKgSiSqMxH4MRusgAERibIADMxyEIYdpwBJVjNJMS4GHAYATIuuQZDBIiwqBVywqI1ywqOUAAPrFMZj7SuAJDaQsjEOHAOBqXAsLofsrjGZsZ7wAwUBkK4ECIIxkynAuy4eZBJDQYQsIPM%208A8EaPEKviCTmkJlCfju0niZJcCBCgVCFcpLQAOqClgUBUbmIgnKa-FUGwBy2oQ1gPMAQA)

[Playground Link 2](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/FAYw9gdgzgLgBCAhgG2QI0SA1gFTABQCcwBbASygFM4BeORKATwhDgB4BBOSgDxkogATKPQiMA2gF0ANHABi3PgOFwAFAGEAQgC41hSlACuyGLsRiAlLQB8oxrIB0TxIQDmUXRys1b5xtdUAM0MWXTlHZzcPOC9dIlIKSjZ8F0QSSn5CKGTU9MzsuWtxAAZJItLbHzgAb2A4ergAeka4AEkSdMEyRH5kRjh9GENCCDgyQLgYAAtqYJYYMkh6N0N0iHgKOBDBSkCyCEpBWRgwegA3MDJBbkJiLIc6hvG1OdYad62hXf3Dq1qGgEISBQMDISgOADuLggqgA5HIQiAFkttt8Dtd9ggUOhMLgCMRyFQHLCLI9AQMMsNRogoWR4PFCeD9AArShI1RkwEHCFwACitzAhDhCPmi1GqL26LGoyQqAw2DwDMSxNJ5PqqoaAF9OeBoPBZchaHBuXAlVRVKp9CDkGdKLIWWyYN5bP81a8LVbQbaAMowQjOmqctVjCaWgxeyi%20whwACEHwlP0EfyDwYagypFOttrDWcjfo1qbgmu4yCogcL5PTIwprPZJv5dzhADlToIeogKUMRocSQXU9rg5qIg4XO4%205q%201WZdjgNrgDBGAAHag4eJoMEkABKlBIYFt24YSzoISwEDAEIgAG5gMAdiBkC5qLrYHBt7vbWuN7pVAb5Vhv4QugQKsaCUP6NhwBcVyyIuhBXEBIFgbIsBgIuAAiPSULosBwRAriyBQHCLrBYA8Bh-C6GgYCgpQ5j2rRIIQLoq7EOuO5vnulAHoxAZQYIN6-riioEokqgcR%20rEbrIABE0myAAzMchCGHacCyVYzSTEuBhwGAEyLrkGRgSIsKwVcsKiNcsKjlAAD6xQWY%200rgCQBkLGxDhwDg2lwLCOH7K4FmbGe8AMFAZCuBAiBsZMpwLsuvnASQoGELCDzPvAPBGoJCr4gk5riZQn47gpMlyXAgQoFQZUaS0ADqgpYFA9G5iIJymiJVBsActqENYDzAAwzCsKoAauvUGVwP0dA0ogdJwFlmn9FMDBaQlSUpbOwBAA)

Comment: My use case does not involve the kind of functions that `util.promisify` works for, unfortunately.  My interaction is with a custom API to an EMR which can call the provided callback, depending on which function I execute, with anything from nothing, a number representing success/fail code, a string result, a JSON object....  Let me see if your example will work for me and I'll get back to you.

Comment: Maybe I was unclear about exactly what I was trying to do. I think `Paramater<T>` might help, but I don't understand it at all, the link you gave me explains exactly nothing and has a half dozen examples that make no sense to me, so I am doing some more research. After copying the provided code into my project in place of my original function, I immediately got a dozen compile errors (mostly `type 'void' is not assignable to type 'x'`)....

Comment: ...  An example function signature that I would be providing as the first argument: `RemoveProblem: (callback: Function, prid: number, stopDate: string, isApproxDate: boolean, reason: TProblemRemoveReason) => void`.  the 'callback' function receives whatever result `RemoveProblem` generates, `RemoveProblem` is a black box I have no access to.  `callbackToPromise` allows me to call `RemoveProblem` as a promise instead of creating a callback function for each use of it. But I have no type safety passing `prid, stopDate, isApproxDate, reason` (etc) in spite of having the interface defined.

Comment: Maybe you can edit your question to involve your exact use case you have an I can adjust accordingly. FWIW it seems like this solution _does_ give the type safety you want for that example signature, can you give another example that breaks it? I've edited an additional playground link to the bottom of the answer, take a look.

Comment: I just updated the question with some more details. I skimmed your playground link and one thing that stands out to me is that it *shouldn't* resolve to `Promise<never>`, for RemoveProblem it should be `Promise<number>`, but other functions I use it on vary.

Comment: Typescript cannot infer the return type for that example because the callback is given type `Function`. That is mostly not your problem to fix, the owner of the `RemoveProblem` code should have given a more accurate type to the callback argument (such as `(arg: number) => void`). The `Function` type includes _zero_ information on what parameters it takes so there is no way for TypeScript to infer that it would be (in this case) a number.

Comment: I can change the signature that Typescript is looking for; the api was provided mainly in an undescribed list of javascript function signatures that I had to adapt from AngularJS to begin with. I tried changing the signature in the interface I describe them in to `((return: number) => void)`, but then I get `Type 'number | void' is not assignable to type 'number'.  Type 'void' is not assignable to type 'number'.ts(2322)` on the line where I am trying to assign a variable to await that promise.  I might be able to make that work with a check or two afterward though.

Comment: That's odd, can you edit a reproduction of that into your question? If all you changed was from `Function` to `(return: number) => void` then I don't see how it differs from the working example in the (second) playground link.

Comment: Ah, actually looking closer at your code the `void` is coming out of your `.catch` branch. It looks like the promise for `callbackToPromise(...).then(...)` correctly resolves to `Promise<number>`. But since you do not return anything in your `.catch` branch, the promise can possible also resolve to `void`. To fix, either check the result after awaiting (as you suggest) or don't use `.catch` and instead capture the error in the `await`ing function.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/237473/discussion-between-crice-and-dwllama).

Answer (score 1):

Still not sure to understand you requirement, but below you can check this recursive generic function that I've created to run Google APIs.
The function has an async function as an argument as well as the parameters of the function (and additionnal arguments related to the execution)
This is typesafe as in the function decalaration, ...args is typeof U[, and the args parameter is also U.

```
    import { GaxiosResponse } from "gaxios";

const execGoogleApiRecurrent = async <
  R,
  T extends Record<string, any>,
  U extends Record<string, any>,
  K extends Record<string, any>
>(
  rootApi: R,
  funct: (...args: U[]) => Promise<GaxiosResponse<T>>,
  key: keyof T,
  previous: K[],
  nextPageToken: string | undefined,
  args: U
): Promise<K[]> => {
  if (nextPageToken) {
    args = {
      ...args,
      pageToken: nextPageToken,
    };
  }
  const calll = await funct.call(rootApi, args);

  previous = [...previous, ...calll.data[key]];

  if (calll.data.nextPageToken) {
    previous = [
      ...(await execGoogleApiRecurrent(
        rootApi,
        funct,
        key,
        previous,
        calll.data.nextPageToken,
        args
      )),
    ];
  }

  return previous;
};
```

example to call tis recursive function is

```
const builds = await execGoogleApiRecurrent<
      admin_directory_v1.Resource$Resources$Buildings,
      admin_directory_v1.Schema$Buildings,
      admin_directory_v1.Params$Resource$Resources$Buildings$List,
      admin_directory_v1.Schema$Building
    >(this._api, this._api.list, "buildings", [], undefined, {
      auth: this._auth,
      customer: "ddds",

    });
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer! I find the `<>` notation still pretty difficult to read but I *think* that would probably address the problem. CRice's answer above solved the question directly though and I have it in use already.